# Python: update/refresh dictionary with variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple dictionary storing paths. This variable is stored in a file.

I would like to update my dictionary with help of a variable.

`settings.py`

```
from datetime import date

ENV = 'dev'
PATH = "myPathA"
TODAY = date.today()
DIC = {
    "month": "/data/{}/{}/{}/".format(ENV, PATH, TODAY.strftime('%m.%y')),
    "day": "/data/{}/{}/{}/".format(ENV, PATH, TODAY.strftime('%d.%m')),
}
```

`process.py`

```
import settings

def myFunc(path, frequency='day'):
    settings.PATH  = path
    print(settings.DIC[frequency])
```

If I call `myFunc("NewCoolPath", 'day')` I will get something like `/data/dev/myPathA/dd.mm/`. I understand that DIC variable in `settings.py` is loaded at the beginning with the line `import settings`. Is there a way to rebuild `settings.DIC` without reloading the `settings.py` file?

I know I could create a function that builds and returns the string, but I'm curious if there is a way of updating a dictionary with respect of new variable inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

**settings.py**

```py
from datetime import date

def dicFunction () :
    return {
        "month": "/data/{}/{}/{}/".format(ENV, PATH, TODAY.strftime('%m.%y')),
        "day": "/data/{}/{}/{}/".format(ENV, PATH, TODAY.strftime('%d.%m')),
    }

ENV = 'dev'
PATH = "myPathA"
TODAY = date.today()
DIC = dicFunction

#here DIC() recalculates the string
```

**process.py**

```py
import settings

def myFunc(path, frequency='day'):
    settings.PATH  = path
    print(settings.DIC()[frequency]) #add the function call
```

it's just an attempt, but it seems to give the expected result

https://repl.it/@gui3/StableNumbEmbeds-3